# XMLHttpRequest on load in saveback to calling object

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to load in many json files for a HTML5 game that will serve as sprite sheets. Previously I've did this synchronously but my new goal is to do this asynchronously.

I have run into a problem though where I'm trying to saving back to the calling object. This is so the information loaded can be used later and so a flag (loaded) can be set so the system knows when a resource has been loaded. Below is my XMLHttpRequest code. I have substituted "spritesheet" for what ever the call should be to save back to the parent.

```
function SpriteSheet(filename)
{
  var tmpFileName = "json/" + filename;
  this.loaded = false;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET",tmpFileName,true);
  xhr.onload = function(event){
    var parsed = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    "spritesheet".img=new Image();
    "spritesheet".img.src = "imgs/" + parsed["imgLoc"];
    "spritesheet".animations = parsed["animations"];
    "spritesheet".sprites = parsed["sprites"];
    "spritesheet".loaded = true;
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Can somebody inform me how I can save back to the the parent or if this is completely the wrong approach can they point me in the direction of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that by creating a var in the 'class' that is a reference to the object and using it in the onload function works, for example:

```
function SpriteSheet(filename)
{
  var tmpFileName = "json/" + filename;
  this.loaded = false;
  var caller = this;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET",tmpFileName,true);
  xhr.onload = function(event){
    var parsed = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    caller.img=new Image();
    caller.img.src = "imgs/" + parsed["imgLoc"];
    caller.animations = parsed["animations"];
    caller.sprites = parsed["sprites"];
    caller.loaded = true;
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```